# Extension loading a content script triggers a warning when published to the chrome web store

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'd like to split my Chrome extension's script into several files. For this purpose, as far as I understand, I need to add a "content_scripts" property to the manifest file. When I publish to the Chrome Web Store, I get a warning message that my extension requires extensive permissions and that reviewing the extension will take more time, and that I'd better do it differently.

Originally, I had one single js file including data and functions. I don't like that, so I wanted to have separate js files for data and functions. So I took the data to a new data.js file and the only way I've found to make it work is to have a "content_script" property inside the manifest file.

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["data.js"]
    }
],
```

The "matches" property seems to be required. My understanding is that this <all_url> value causes the Chrome Store to warn me that this is too much of a permission. They advise me to use "permissions": ["activeTab"] instead. But I already have that in my manifest. So I'm a bit confused as to how I could just add a content script without requiring additional permission, since it's just another embedded js file, and I don't see why that would require more permission than the original background javascript file.

Comment: A content script is needed to access/modify DOM of the web pages. If you don't need that, don't use a content script. Also `<all_urls>` means that an instance of your content script runs on every web page so you should only use it if you really need it everywhere. Depending on what your extensions does **exactly** there may be different ways of implementing it. Separation of files by itself is unrelated here because an extension consists of strictly defined parts each designed to serve a certain goal as described in the documentation for that part.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm. Accessing & modifying the DOM of web pages is what my extension does. It does that only on demand, when the user clicks the extension icon. Actually, I was able to implement that with just a background script. Separating scripts was more for practical purposes to me, so I understand that I went in the wrong direction with content_scripts. I think I've found a solution to my issue, so I'll post it here.

Comment: No need to declare the content script in manifest.json if you inject it using chrome.tabs.executeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed using several separate js files by referencing them from the background script :

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"script1.js"});
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"script2.js"});
});
```

It works fine, and doesn't cause the Chrome Web Store to prompt a permission warning. So it seems a much better way for what I intended to do.